# Maximum size/offset of streamed File using Ada.Streams.Stream_IO.Read

Tags: io, filestream, ada, gnat

I try to read specific blocks of Data (around 4096 bytes) from a (possibly) huge file.

Using `Ada.Streams.Stream_IO.Read()` with the GNAT compiler, what would be the maximum offset that I could use? That is, if I wanted to read the last 4 kilobytes of the file, using

```
type Block_Array is array (1..4096) of Positive;
...
Ada.Streams.Stream_IO.Read(File, Block_Array, Last, Offset);
```

how big could the Offset be (and therefore the file)?

Doing a bit of research, `Offset` seems in GNAT to be defined as `2 ** mod Standard'Address_Size` [1], which would be `2^32` on a 32-bit machine. It is not absolutely clear to me if this refers to bits, bytes, kilobytes or even some obscure multiple.

Supposing that it means bytes, wouldn't that mean the biggest file I could handle would be 32 gigabytes (`(2^32*8)/1024^3`) large? If so, is there a way to make this larger?

---

Since it was suggested that I haven't checked the (language) reference manual, here is the research that lead me to the question in the first place:

In [2] the `read` procedure is defined as:

```
procedure Read (File : in  File_Type;
                Item : out Stream_Element_Array;
                Last : out Stream_Element_Offset;
                From : in  Positive_Count);
```

A little further up:

```
type    Count          is range 0 .. *implementation-defined*;
subtype Positive_Count is Count range 1 .. Count'Last;
```

As one can see, the actual range of `Count` is *implementation-defined*. Since I am using the GNAT compiler (see above), I checked [1]. This states that

> The Standard I/O packages described in Annex A for
>   [...] Ada.Stream_IO [...]
>   are implemented using the C library streams facility; where
>   [...] All input/output operations use fread/fwrite.

In the same documentation below

```
function fread
     (buffer : voids;
      size : size_t;
      count : size_t;
      stream : FILEs)
```

where

```
type size_t is mod 2 ** Standard'Address_Size;
```

Again, `Standard'Address_Size` would be `32` on a 32-bit machine (I've also checked prior to asking that this is the case on my computer). I am also still not sure after reading both the language reference manual AND the implementation documentation of GNAT if `Stream_Element_Offset` refers to bytes or something other.

But again, supposing that it means bytes, wouldn't that mean the biggest file I could handle would be 32 gigabytes (`(2^32*8)/1024^3`) large? If so, is there a way to make this larger?

[1]: [The Implementation of Standard I/O - GNAT Reference Manual](http://docs.adacore.com/gnat_rm-docs/html/gnat_rm/gnat_rm/the_implementation_of_standard_i_o.html)

[2]: [Ada Reference Manual - A.12.1 The Package Streams.Stream_IO](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-12-1.html#I6531)

Comment: It doesn't look like you have looked up the specification of the package `Ada.Streams.Stream_IO` in the language reference manual (section A.12.1).

Comment: @JacobSparreAndersen Well it does look like in fact you haven't. Please see the edit in my question. Also, condescension never helps. If there is something that I have missed (which is likely and part of why I am asking), please feel free to provide an insightful answer.

Comment: 32 gigabits, not gigabytes.

Comment: Actually, I think, 16 gigabits - `Stream_Element_Offset` is signed.

Comment: Ah yes. So you also think `Stream_Element_Offset` refers to bits, not bytes? I've read that the `Stream_Element_Array` might use bytes. But I got really, really confused about that part. Your comments really seem plausible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Mac OS X, with FSF GCC 5.1.0, there is

```ada
procedure Read
  (File : File_Type;
   Item : out Stream_Element_Array;
   Last : out Stream_Element_Offset;
   From : Positive_Count);
```

where

```ada
type Count is new Stream_Element_Offset
  range 0 .. Stream_Element_Offset’Last;

subtype Positive_Count is Count range 1 .. Count’Last;            --'
--  Index into file, in stream elements
```

and (in `Ada.Streams`)

```ada
type Stream_Element_Offset is new Long_Long_Integer;
```

which is 64 bits .. should be enough.

**However**, as Alex points out, GNAT GPL 2014 has

```ada
type Stream_Element_Offset is range
  -(2 ** (Standard'Address_Size - 1)) ..
  +(2 ** (Standard'Address_Size - 1)) - 1;
```

which means that, on a 32-bit machine, you’re limited to 2 gigabyte files.

The latest FSF GCC sources (as for 5.1.0 above) have been changed; we’ll have to wait until GNAT GPL 2015 to see which is definitive.

As a further cause for concern, the GNAT GPL 2014 code for `Ada.Streams.Stream_IO.Set_Position` (an internal subprogram) is

```
procedure Set_Position (File : File_Type) is
   use type System.CRTL.long;
   use type System.CRTL.ssize_t;
   R : int;
begin
   if Standard'Address_Size = 64 then
      R := fseek64 (File.Stream,
                    System.CRTL.ssize_t (File.Index) - 1, SEEK_SET);
   else
      R := fseek (File.Stream,
                  System.CRTL.long (File.Index) - 1, SEEK_SET);
   end if;

   if R /= 0 then
      raise Use_Error;
   end if;
end Set_Position;
```

whereas the GCC 5.1.0 version (which has no alternative implementations) is

```ada
procedure Set_Position (File : File_Type) is
   use type System.CRTL.int64;
   R : int;
begin
   R := fseek64 (File.Stream, System.CRTL.int64 (File.Index) - 1, SEEK_SET);

   if R /= 0 then
      raise Use_Error;
   end if;
end Set_Position;
```

If your system has `fseek64()` - or possibly `fseeko()`, which takes an `off_t` rather than a `long` for the `offset` parameter - and friends (I think it must, looking at the code above) I would think it wouldn’t be too hard to write your own version of `Ada.Streams.Stream_IO` to always use the 64-bit functions. Probably easiest to call it `My_Stream_IO` and grit your teeth about compiler warnings on use of internal GNAT units rather than try to slot it into the `Ada` hierarchy.

Comment: That is true but only for FSF GCC, not GNAT as in my answer. Since Mac OS X is 64-bit-only for a very while now it therefore seems logical for it to have 64 bit long variables. It seems to me that on 64bit machines GNAT would also allow for such huge files, but specifically in 32-bit machines, there seems to be a limitation for nowadays rather reasonable filesizes.

Comment: FSF GCC *is* Gnat. If you're using some other build of Gnat it may be helpful to say so - and follow the approach Simon outlined to see if the answer for the implementation you're using differs from Simon's.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Ah I did not know that. Then FSF probably stands for Free Software Foundation? Well then I am using `gcc (GCC) 4.7.4 20140401 for GNAT GPL gpl-2014 (20140405)`. And for that version I thought the above references (using in good faith the same approach as Simon) would conclude to my "answer". Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the range of a scalar type, you can access the minimum and maximum values using `<type>'First` and `<type>'Last`:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Check_Range is
   use Ada.Text_IO;
   subtype Type_To_Check is Integer;
begin
   Put (Type_To_Check'Image (Type_To_Check'First));
   Put (" .. ");
   Put (Type_To_Check'Image (Type_To_Check'Last));
   New_Line;
end Check_Range;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access larger files than what the standard library supports, you can import the operating system functions giving access to the largest files allowed by your operating system.

The details of importing functions from other languages is specified in annex B in the language reference manual.